C# - Datagridview - Generar columnas desde IDE o Generarlas desde un método Void al cargar el formulario WindowsForms?
Me gustaría saber cuál es la mejor práctica a la hora de visualizar las columnas de un datagriview:
Es mejor crear y definir las columnas desde el IDE o es mejor crear un método para crearlas, definirlas y establecer sus propiedades, al momento de cargar el formulario Windows Forms.
